# Delete comment from frontend in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a way to add a button to my custom comment template **without confirmation page**.

My comment template :

```
function format_comment() { 
    echo '<b>'.get_comment_author().'</b> ';
    echo get_comment_text().'</br> ';
    echo edit_comment_link();
}
```

I know there is something with "WPNONCE" (Ex:&_wpnonce=e465b569b3)

Edit / Delete comments links :

```
if ( ! function_exists( 't5_comment_mod_links' ) )
{
    add_filter( 'edit_comment_link', 't5_comment_mod_links', 10, 2 );

    function t5_comment_mod_links( $link, $id )
    {
        $template = ' <a class="comment-edit-link" href="%1$s%2$s">%3$s</a>';
        $admin_url = admin_url( "comment.php?c=$id&action=" );

        // Mark as Spam.
        $link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'cdc&dt=spam', __( 'Spam' ) );
        // Delete.
        $link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'cdc', __( 'Delete' ) );

        // Approve or unapprove.
        $comment = get_comment( $id );

        if ( '0' === $comment->comment_approved )
        {
            $link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'approvecomment', __( 'Approve' ) );
        }
        else
        {
            $link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'unapprovecomment', __( 'Unapprove' ) );
        }

        return $link;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not that trivial if you want to delete comment on the front end. You'd need to create an ajax call that will call the function that will delete the comment (you'll need an ID of the comment), and on complete method you can simply delete the comment from the DOM. A bit too broad imo... Also would this be available only to admin? If so, what's the need of it when he can just go to the post and delete it there in the backend?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have more than 300 authors in my wordpress installation. I would like to give the opportunity to moderate live from frontend. I know there are some plugins doing it but if I use custom template, I can't display the plugins. Do you have more information about what you sugegsted plz ?

Comment: Tbh, any moderation should be done from the backend. Just create custom role for that and give certain people access to deleting comments, way more easier than creating this

Comment: I know, but originaly I didn't want authors to modify comments from others, so I blocked dashboard because I didn't find a way to block editing a comment and still allow to delete a comment